# Relative Cell References Based on Row Location of Form Buttons

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have created a VBA program that automatically inserts form control buttons for a given range in column N (Where I need these buttons to show up).

These form buttons are embedded with another sub (SendEmail) that creates an e-mail based off of information found in other columns in the row the form button resides.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to make the cell references relative based on the button a user will click in anyone of the 5,000 rows.

For example, if the form button is in N120 how can I get the cell references to be c120, f120 and j120 (using the cell reference in SendEmail) without re-writing the code 5,000 times.  The code below is what I have so far:

```
Sub CreateButtons()
Dim i As Long
Dim shp As Object
Dim dblLeft As Double
Dim dblTop As Double
Dim dblWidth As Double
Dim dblHeight As Double

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    dblLeft = .Columns("N:N").Left
    dblWidth = .Columns("N:N").Width
    For i = 2 To 5000
        dblHeight = .Rows(i).Height
        dblTop = .Rows(i).Top
        Set shp = .Buttons.Add(dblLeft, dblTop, dblWidth, dblHeight)
        shp.OnAction = "SendEmail"
        shp.Characters.Text = "Email"
    Next i
End With
End Sub

 Private Sub SendEmail()
   Dim Outlook_App As Object
   Dim Outlook_Mail As Object

   Set Outlook_App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set Outlook_Mail = Outlook_App.CreateItem(0)
   Dim strbody As String

     strbody = "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
     "Our records indicate we need to receive the following items from " & 
     Range("c2") & " on or before " & Range("f2") & ":" & vbNewLine & 
     vbNewLine & _
     "" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
     "Thank you,"

  On Error Resume Next
    With Outlook_Mail
      .To = Range("j2").Value
      .Subject = "ACTION NEEDED: Request for Items"
      .body = strbody
      .display
  End With
  End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe a great idea with poor execution?  Patrick you only need one button, the buttons all do the same thing.  When you click the "one button" prompt the user to select a cell in the column you wish to process at the row you wish to process.  Then you can very easily grab the row or column of the target selection and do whatever you want from there (even to adjacent rows and columns).  Or you could look at worksheet selection change for your procedure.  Anyway if you are worried about scrolling away from your button put it at the top and freeze panes or select do not move with cells

Comment: If you don't want the button at all then record a macro and run it manually when needed to select the cell or make it a custom ribbon tab item to fire the function/macro.  I now where you are going with this and thought that way once before, but you don't need 5,000 buttons, you need one button / or one function because the function guts are the same, the inputs (cell locations are not).  Slow down and rethink this for a minute, don't dedicate a column to a pile of buttons, refresh is terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I agree with @Wookies-Will-Code, if this is what you want, than here's the answer to your question.

```
Sub SendEmail()
  Dim strbody As String
  Dim This As Range   'This is where the magic starts

  'This is the actual magic.
  Set This = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address)
  '
  'Now that the parent cell object is determined, we can use a simple 
  'offset to collect the necessary data for the email body.
  '
  strbody = "To: " & This.Offset(0, -4) & vbNewLine & _
            "Subject: ACTION NEEDED: Request for Items" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Our records indicate we need to receive the following items " & vbNewLine & _
            This.Offset(0, -11).value & " on or before " & _
            This.Offset(0, -8).value & ":" & vbNewLine & _
            vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Thank you,"
  MsgBox strbody
End Sub
```

Performance wise you might concider switching of screenupdate, events and calculation untill all buttons are created, and even than it's not a fast subroutine. In my test it still took 13 seconds to complete, and I have a pretty fast computer. So you might go with @Wookies-Will-Code advise and rethink your procedure.

```
Sub CreateButtons()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim shp As Object
  Dim dblLeft As Double
  Dim dblTop As Double
  Dim dblWidth As Double
  Dim dblHeight As Double

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  '
  'Do your stuff
  '
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: C. van Dorsten - Thank you that worked perfectly!  For the created buttons sub is there anyway I can only add a button if there is a value in column A?  I am trying to trim down the number of buttons inserted and I am removing duplicate values in column A as these are not needed.  Thanks Again!

Comment: Yeah ofcourse you can only create buttons when certain conditions are met. Somthing in the line of for i = 2 to 500: if some_conditon_is_met then create_the_button.  Good luck.